# Docker publishing port not working in Windows 10

Tags: reactjs, windows, docker, port, vite

I'm learning docker and facing a problem while publishing port from docker container to the host

I created an image for a dummy React app (using Vite) using the command `docker build -t react-app .`

Below is the `Dockerfile` -

```
FROM node:16.17.0-alpine3.16
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
USER app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json  .
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5173
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

And created a container from the image with the command `docker run -d --name my-app -p 3000:5173 react-app`

> NOTE - Port `5173` is the default port used by Vite

But when I tried to access `localhost:3000` from my host machine, it didn't work.

I also tried using the container IP address instead of localhost and didn't work. I used `docker exec my-app ifconfig` command to get container IP address

Some suggested using the IP address mentioned under `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and that didn't help either.

Could someone please help me with this? Thanks!

Edit:
Here is the output of `docker logs` command -

[image: Output of docker logs command]

Comment: Are you sure the app in your container is listening on 5173 port and not 3000? What is docker logs containername command show?

Comment: @zsolt Attached the output of `docker logs` command

Comment: Got the problem. In the output of `docker logs` command, it says `use --host to expose`. I simply had to add `--host` to the `vite` command in package.json. It worked!

Comment: Great! Always check logs first :)

Comment: @DhilipH please post your solution as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Vite's official documentation, it requires us to pass in `--host` argument to specify which IP addresses the server should listen on.

More details here - https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-host

Updated `package.json` to fix the problem.

```json
...
"scripts": {
   "dev": "vite --host",
   "build": "vite build",
   "preview": "vite preview --host"
},
...
```